# Metadata download error while adding web service reference

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, visual-studio-2013, wsdl

I want to use the web service of this site:
http://genecodis.cnb.csic.es/webservices

I tried to add the service reference to my windows form .Net project using the "wsdl" file (http://genecodis.cnb.csic.es/wsdl/GenecodisWS.wsdl) but this error occurred:

> *There was an error downloading 'genecodis.cnb.csic.es/wsdl/GenecodisWS.wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.*

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a plain console project with a service reference to the same URL: http://genecodis.cnb.csic.es/wsdl/GenecodisWS.wsdl

I got the same exact error:

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://genecodis.cnb.csic.es/wsdl/GenecodisWS.wsdl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

It looks like an issue with the setup of their web service. I would suggest contacting whomever is running the site about this.

P.S. I also tried adding it as a regular service (not web). Got the same error but a little more if it helps: `Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.`

Comment: Thank you for your attention Paul